# NordVPN on Arch Linux Limited Connectivity

Tags: arch-linux, vpn, internet, connectivity, nordvpn

I am using the NordVPN-bin package from AUR on my Arch Linux system (Manjaro KDE Plasma).
Connecting etc works just fine, but after I connected to the services I always get the notification: "Limited connectivity" on my WLAN/LAN.
This sometimes leads to that I have no internet access anymore. Then I have to deactivate my internet connection and reactivate it. That sometimes works, but sometimes I have to reboot.

I have deactivated all additional settings for nordvpn (Kill Switch, Cybersec, etc).
Also I deactivated IPv6 for my network adapters and I have removed the preinstalled package "openvpn".

Everything does not help and NordVPN Customer Service cannot help me, since Arch Linux is not official supported.

Hope someone could help me out here!

Settings and Status:

[image: Settings and status of NordVPN]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact setup as you, I use Nordvpn on Manjaro KDE and sometimes I get that error.

This is the script I use to fix it if the connection says 'limited' or if it drops. I put these functions in my `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`

```
# Run 'nord-fix' if you have issues connecting
nord-fix(){
    clear
    timeout 10s nordvpn set killswitch disabled
    timeout 10s nordvpn set autoconnect disabled
    timeout 10s nordvpn disconnect
    timeout 10s nordvpn set autoconnect enabled 
    timeout 10s nordvpn set killswitch enabled
    sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
    sudo iptables -F INPUT
    sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    sudo iptables -F OUTPUT
    sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
    timeout 10s nordvpn connect us
}

# Run 'nord-update' if it's completely unusable.
# It re-installs the app and asks you to log back in.
nord-update(){
    clear
    sudo yay -R nordvpn -y
    sudo yay -S nordvpn -y
    
    # this command allows the system to access others on the network
    nordvpn whitelist add subnet 192.168.0.0/24

    nordvpn login
}
```

This is the arch wiki related to Arch Nordvpn troubleshooting
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NordVPN#Troubleshooting